# Which public parks or places accessible to tourists are on the Thousand Islands?

Tags: canada, thousand-islands

*Split off from my [other question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/57441/how-to-explore-the-thousand-islands) about getting to the islands.*

Which public parks or places accessible to tourists are on the [Thousand Islands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thousand_Islands)?

Comment: "the wind she blow on Lac St Pierre", if you are of a literary bent, it might be worth checking out locales immortalised by William Henry Drummond. But yeah, the question invites closure.

Comment: @Flimzy - I was having trouble formulating my question. Maybe it is better now? I am asking not to be recommended a place but for there existence and location. For all I know, many islands could be private property. Feel free to help formulate the question as a question :)

Comment: It does seem a lot more on-topic now.

Comment: I would have been happy to answer both of these questions in a single answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here is the official tourism site of the Thousand Islands.](http://www.visit1000islands.com/)

As my other answer said, the larger islands (like Wolfe island and Howe island) are accessible by car ferry. The smaller islands (anything where the map doesn't show a road) are mostly privately owned and not accessible to the public. The exceptions are those that are specifically open as tourist attractions. Two of the main ones are:

- Boldt Castle on Heart island
- Singer Castle on Dark island

[Thousand islands National Park](http://www.pc.gc.ca/eng/pn-np/on/lawren/index.aspx) owns several of the islands and various sites in the area. They are generally accessible to the public, but don't have much to see on them.

Places open to tourists in the area of the Thousand islands include:

- Boat cruises out of Kingston or Gananoque
- Various War of 1812 battle sites
- Martello tower at Kingston